# Regex in python for validating mail

Tags: python, regex

I am learning regex for validating an email id, for which the regex I made is the following:

```
regex = r'^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,})$'
```

Here `someone@...com` is showing as valid but it should not, how can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the regular expression suggested on this [site](https://emailregex.com/) which properly shows that the email `someone@...com` is invalid, I quickly wrote up an example using their suggestion below, happy coding!

```
>>>import re
>>>email = "someone@...com"

>>>regex = re.compile(r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)")
>>>print(re.match(regex, email))
None
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it matches *someone@...com* is that the dot is in the character class here `@([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)` and is repeated 1 or more times and it can therefore also match `...`

What you can do is place the dot after the character class, and use that whole part in a repeating group.

If you put the `-` at the end you don't have to escape it.

**Note** that that character class at the start also has a dot.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eKoN3I/1)